# Vue3 - MIME type error when using path params

Tags: vue.js, vite

I seem to keep getting MIME type error when using path parameters.

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://mysite.subdomain.com/nfc/assets/index.8a364bbf.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

The code in my router looks like this, though it happens with any path that tries using params:

```
{
    path: '/nfc/omega',
    meta: { layout: Default },
    component: () => import('@/views/NFC.vue'),
    beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
        if (!await isAuthenticated()) {
            next()
        }
        else {
            next('/transactions')
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that the error is being caused because it's looking at the path `https://mysite.subdomain.com/nfc/assets/`. I imagine I need to change something in my vite config so that it always looks at the absolute path instead of the `nfc` path but I'm unsure what change is required.

**Edit:** Just to add, everything works fine locally but not in production when the project is built.